# CalDAV and Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, calendar, caldav

Does anyone know of a library for CalDAV on classic asp.

I've tried creating a domain cal.example.com and using the following code in a HTML page, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know why this example will not work? Basically all I want to do is setup a simple service for an iPhone to connect to.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
   PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN
   VERSION:2.0
   BEGIN:VEVENT
   UID:1@example.com
   SUMMARY:One-off Meeting
   DTSTAMP:20041210T183904Z
   DTSTART:20041207T120000Z
   DTEND:20041207T130000Z
   END:VEVENT
   BEGIN:VEVENT
   UID:2@example.com
   SUMMARY:Weekly Meeting
   DTSTAMP:20041210T183838Z
   DTSTART:20041206T120000Z
   DTEND:20041206T130000Z
   RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY
   END:VEVENT
   BEGIN:VEVENT
   UID:2@example.com
   SUMMARY:Weekly Meeting
   RECURRENCE-ID:20041213T120000Z
   DTSTAMP:20041210T183838Z
   DTSTART:20041213T130000Z
   DTEND:20041213T140000Z
   END:VEVENT
   END:VCALENDAR
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: With what contenttype are you serving this? And what do you mean by _doesn't seem to work_? Any errors or messages?

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a [.Net library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) for ASP.Net , but for  asp classic, I think you have to build your own.

Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2007/12/12/serving-icalendar-from-asp.aspx) for some advice how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to this and am only starting to do my research but I think that for it to work on eg. iPhone you need a webcal:// url type. If so then above might work. Try it, if you havent already found a solution...